# Change foreign key unsignedBigInteger field to be text field in migration laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I have a table `foo` and a migration for it like this (just showing the up method):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('foo', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('boo_id');
    });

    Schema::table('foo', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('boo_id')->references('id')->on('boos');
    });
}
```

So I have a `boo_id` foreign key on `boos.id`. Now I would like to create a migration that will alter the field `boo_id` to be text and not be foreign key anymore. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to delete the foreign key and the index created for the foreign and then change the data type of the column. A migration like this would help:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('foo', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('foo_boo_id_foreign');
        $table->dropIndex('foo_boo_id_foreign');
    });

    Schema::table('foo', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->text('boo_id')->change();
    });
}
```

Please note that they must be in two seperate `Schema::table` bodies, otherwise you will face an error: `Syntax error or access violation: 1170 BLOB/TEXT column 'boo_id' used in key specification without a key length (SQL: ALTER TABLE foo CHANGE boo_id boo_id TEXT DEFAULT NULL)`. Also note that the names passed to `dropForeign` and `dropIndex` functions might be different for you, you should check that in your DB to be sure, as that naming convention is not mandatory.